# Slim Framework and Angular Restful API - Getting 500 and 404 errors

Tags: php, angular, rest, api, slim

Creating a simple Crud application using slim framework and angular.. i have my database table displaying, but when i try to click into a single author to edit, the page shows up blank with a 404 error like this:
[image]

and when i try to add i get a POST 500 (internal server error)
Im new to this framework and i feel i could have an issue with my .htaccess file but im very unsure

here is my code for getting a single author and adding a author

```
function getAuthor($id) {
$sql = "select * FROM authors WHERE AuthorID=".$id." ORDER BY AuthorID";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $authors = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($authors);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}

function addAuthor() {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $author = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO authors (AuthorFirstName, AuthorLastName, 
AuthorEmail) VALUES (:AuthorFirstName, :AuthorLastName, :AuthorEmail)";
    try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("AuthorFirstName", $author->AuthorFirstName);
    $stmt->bindParam("AuthorLastName", $author->AuthorLastName);
    $stmt->bindParam("AuthorEmail", $author->AuthorEmail);

    $stmt->execute();
    $author->id = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($author);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}
```

my ht.access file

```
RewriteEngine On


# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well, 404 means your route is incorrect.  Also, is there a reason you don't have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` as well as `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]` as per recommended .htaccess?

Comment: Could you show us your `routes` file? Also how are you sending your requests? Could you show us the parameters you're sending and how are you sending them, and in which format?